# Anylogic: Stopping resource pool based on event

Tags: java, production, anylogic

I am modelling a production line in AnyLogic where at some points we have to convert the equipment at specific machine elements (modelled as service + resource pools). It happens only on certain events, i.e. change of product-version (A -> B). Is there a way I can tell a resource pool to stop "now" and have a delay of for example 20 minutes?
I am really struggling since it looks like all of this can only be implemented as distributions etc. but not as a discrete event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Either use the properties of your "ResourcePool" element (under tab "Maintenance, failures...") or the new "Downtime" block.

Both have a good description in the help and example models to get you started.

Also, learn about the "Priority" system for more important tasks so resource make priority decisions, if needed.

Comment: Okay thank you - the downtime block sounds promising. I am using the AnyLogic 8 Learning Edition (provided by my university ...). The Downtime-block is not available in this version, am I right?

Comment: All blocks are available in all versions, afaik.